# Horizontal Parallax Effect - Relative motions between views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

I need a parallax scrolling effect. Something like Make My Trip app home page screen.
Any suggestion please. Demos or examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create two collectionviews with different item sizes and minimumInteritemSpacing. 
Keep user interaction enabled for the collectionview at front but disable it for the other collection view.

On horizontal scroll of front collectionview, scroll the rear collectionview as well.
You can use `scrollViewDidScroll` method for this and scroll the rear collectionview accordingly.